# jQuery - Unable to filter links of a div

Tags: jquery

I want to select all internal links, which are in my document, but not that which are in a special div.

Following shows an example of my site layout:

```
<div id="toppanel">
    <a href="test.php">Test</a>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="menu1.php">Menu1<a>
        <a href="menu2.php">Menu2<a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Startseite</a></li>
        <li class="sep">|</li>
        <li>Datenschutz</li>
        <li class="sep">|</li>
        <li>Impressum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is following:

```
$("a[target!='_blank']").not('#toppanel').live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(href, function(data) {
         $('#content').html(data);
    });
});
```

The problem is that with this none of the links are working. If I use the jQuery code without the not() statement, all links working correct, but also that one in the #toppanel-div, which I want to prevent, because that links are used in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the parent elements of the clicked to see if it is a child of `#toppanel` :

```
$("a[target!='_blank']").live("click", function(event) {
    if (!$(this).closest("#toppanel").length) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(href, function(data) {
             $('#content').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeht/)

Comment: Nice solution with a bit of a flaw: `event.preventDefault()` will cancel the event entierly. Thus, the links inside `#toppanel` won't work at all (no matter if you return `true` to let the event bubble, it's cancelled already).

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 it isn't recommended to use live since it is deprecated and will be removed in the next version. Instead you should use `$('body').on('click', 'a[target!="_blank"]', function(e){ ... });`

Comment: The problem here is that there are more divs in the toppanel, where also links can be in, which should also be in the list of filtered links.

Comment: In that case you need to define a method of excluding those links - a class would work better I think.

Answer (score 2):

It may be related to this:

Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected.

from here:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

it may be worth using one of the newer event attachment methods.

Comment: Nice pointer - thanks for making me learn something new today!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to construct the selector you're looking for - **[working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nFc48/)**:

```
$my_elements = $("a[target!='_blank']")
  .not(function(){ return !$(this).closest('#toppanel').length });
```

Your whole snippet would look like this:

```
$("a[target!='_blank']")
 .not(function(){ return !$(this).closest('#toppanel').length })
 .live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(href, function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
});
```

Also, as [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026568/evert) mentioned, `live()` doesn't support chaining properly. You should use `on()` or, if you're using jQuery < 1.7, `delegate()` to attach your events:

```
$("a[target!='_blank']")
 .not(function(){ return !$(this).closest('#toppanel').length })
 .on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(href, function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
});
```

---

Another solution, maybe even a more elegant one, would be to filter the `<div>`s instead of the `<a>`s:

```
$('a[target!="_blank"]', 'div:not("#toppanel")').on('click', function(event){ /* ... */ });
```

The same, leveraging the `selector` argument of `on()`:

```
$('div').not('#toppanel').on('click', 'a[target!="_blank"]', function(event){ /* ... */ });
```

---

*Edit:* Replaced `parentsUntil()` by `closest()` due to performance reasons - see the [jsperf test comparison](http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-parentsuntil)

Comment: I am using your second solution, because this was my initial try, but I didn't know the trick with :not ;)

Comment: Hmm, your solution seems to be that one I was locking for, but it does not work properly. If I use the solution Rory McCrossan all is working. It seems that the .not() functionality is not filtering the links.

Comment: @Develman My solution is working in the jsfiddle – I suspect that `live()` is to blame; cf. the post by Evert.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$("a").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent("div").attr("id") != "toppanel") {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $.get(href, function(data) {
         $('#content').html(data);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will work only if the link is an immediate child of `#toppanel` - better use `closest()`, `parentsUntil()` or the like.